# MVC5 dropdownlist validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make a validation for my dropdownlist in MVC5 that user must select an item but I'm not sure how to do it. I've created my list inside the Model class for some reason and now I don't know how to apply `[Require(ErrorMessage)]` to this program

**cshtml:**

```
<label>Project Type:</label>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Project_Type, Project1.Models.Dropdowns.GetProjectType(), "--Project Type--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    <h6 style="text-emphasis-color:red;text-decoration-color:red" class="error"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project_Type)</h6>
```

**Model:**

```
   public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetProjectType()
    {

    List<SelectListItem> Project_Type = new List<SelectListItem>();

    Project_Type.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "type1" });
    Project_Type.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "type2" });
    Project_Type.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "type3" });
    Project_Type.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "type4" });

    return Project_Type;
    }
```

it has an error when I apply [Require()]

> error image

[image]

Comment: You need a `[Required]` attribute on the `Project_Type` property (and include a `@Htl.ValidationMessgeFor(m => m.Project_Type)` in the view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i got an error after applying [Required]

Comment: `[Require(ErrorMessage = "...")]public string Project_Type { get; set; }`(and you have not added a `Value` property to each `SelectListItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the value of your DD in a variable like follows:

```
[Required(Errormessage="message")] // just add this in your model
public string Project_Type {get;set;}
```

And change your `List` like follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetProjectType()
{

    List<SelectListItem> Project_Type = new List<SelectListItem>();
    Project_Type.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "type1",value="1" });
    Project_Type.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "type2",value="2" });
    Project_Type.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "type3",value="3" });
    Project_Type.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "type4",value="4"});

    return Project_Type;
}
```

Comment: It has to added to the property OP is binding to, not the `List<SelectListItem>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke he need to add field like above code

Comment: Yes I know :) (see my comments to the question)

Comment: why don't set value for ```SelectListItem() { Text = "type1" ``` ?
and add ```using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;```

Comment: @hamedhossani what you mean?